# how to access this.facebookService from other component

Tags: angular

I want to access facebook service inside other component.

This is how I init facebook service in **app.component.ts**

```js
import { FacebookService } from 'ngx-facebook';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
        private facebookService: FacebookService,
    ) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.facebookService.init(initParams);
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the `this.facebookService` from another component

So I can do something like this

in component **hello.ts**

```js
dosomething(){
  this.facebookService.CustomerChat.showDialog()
}
```

I got error can not read property showDialog() of undefined.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try importing the service into your Hello.ts class?

Comment: Well, pass it to constructor in that component. hello.ts

Answer (score 1):

```js
## create a shared service.

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FacebookService } from 'ngx-facebook';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

  public get faceBookService() {
    return this._facebookService;
  }

  constructor(private _facebookService: FacebookService) { 

  }

  public initFacebook(initParams: any) {
    this._facebookService.init(initParams);
  }

}
```

#### Then in your components import this shared service.

```js
import { SharedService } from './services/shared.service.ts';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
        private _sharedService: SharedService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._sharedService.facebookService.init(initParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would he create shared service only to use ngx-facebook? It only makes sense if he will use it for other purposes as well, otherwise it's just adding an extra step while you don't really need it.

Comment: You will use that shared service in the end in order to access the facebook service instance form different components, the most important is the singleton pattern here, you are ensuring a single instance of the service and you can access it from any place. @Dino ok now?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if the shared service doesn't have other purpose than serving the facebookService instance, it's just adding an extra step which is not needed - as you can reference the facebookService instance directly from the components.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are new to Angular. Normally you access the services by injecting them in components constructor.

```
import { FacebookService } from 'ngx-facebook';
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private fb: FacebookService) {}

    callSomeFbMethod() {
       this.fb.someMethod();
    }
}
```

You also have to make sure that the service you are injecting is also injected to `providers` in your `app.module.ts` or which ever module your component depends on. If you are using 3rd party libraries such as this one - ngx-facebook, you will probably have to import the library module and not the service.

```
import { FacebookModule } from 'ngx-facebook';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    FacebookModule.forRoot()
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you create your own service, you import it like this:

```
import { MyService } from 'services/my-service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    MyService
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I did this, I got error Cannot read property 'showDialog' of undefined. Check out my updated question

Comment: Also what is {Myservice}?

Comment: Of course you are getting this error as this.facebookService.CustomerChat is undefined. Did you even research if ngx-facebook has CustomerChat support? I guess no...

Comment: I see. they have no CustomerChat support

Comment: What the alternative. you know?

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular services are basically Singletons (i.e: there is only a single instance of the service wherever you are in the application), you can access them from any component by simply injecting them within the component's constructor.